# How to position image inside container and be under then text?

Tags: html, css

I want to position an image without change my HTML.
I am trying to get the right image "class -> img>right" be lower then text on same header container
without disturbing the text.

The problem -> image cover the text

[image]

---

The solution -> image under the text

[image]

I should be responsive, with height as well

```css
*,
*::after,
*::after {
  margin: 0;
  box-sizing: border-box;
}

html,
body {
  width: 100%;
  min-height: 100vh;
  overflow-x: hidden;
}

body {
  font-family: Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif;
}

.header {
  min-height: 100vh;
  width: 550px;
  position: relative;
  text-align: center;
}

.header > img {
  height: 200px;
  width: 200px;
}

.header > img.left {
  float: left;
}

.header > img.right {
  position: absolute;
  bottom: 0;
  right: 0;
}

header > text > p {
  background-color: lemonchiffon;
}

header > text > p:nth-child(odd) {
  background-color: lightcyan;
}
```

```html
<div class="header">

  <h1>header header header</h1>

  <img src="data:image/jpeg;base64,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" class="left">
  <img src="data:image/jpeg;base64,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" class="right">

  <h2>First draft header....</h2>
  <div class="text">
    <p>draft draft draft draft draft draft draft draft draft draft draft draft draft draft</p>
    <p>draft draft draft draft draft draft draft draft draft draft draft draft draft draft</p>
    <p>draft draft draft draft draft draft draft draft draft draft draft draft draft draft</p>
    <p>draft draft draft draft draft draft draft draft draft draft draft draft draft draft</p>
    <p>draft draft draft draft draft draft draft draft draft draft draft draft draft draft</p>
    <p>draft draft draft draft draft draft draft draft draft draft draft draft draft draft</p>
    <p>draft draft draft draft draft draft draft draft draft draft draft draft draft draft</p>
    <p>draft draft draft draft draft draft draft draft draft draft draft draft draft draft</p>
    <p>draft draft draft draft draft draft draft draft draft draft draft draft draft draft</p>
    <p>draft draft draft draft draft draft draft draft draft draft draft draft draft draft</p>
    <p>draft draft draft draft draft draft draft draft draft draft draft draft draft draft</p>
    <p>draft draft draft draft draft draft draft draft draft draft draft draft draft draft</p>
    <p>draft draft draft draft draft draft draft draft draft draft draft draft draft draft</p>
    <p>draft draft draft draft draft draft draft draft draft draft draft draft draft draft</p>

  </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

```css
*,
*::after,
*::after {
  margin: 0;
  box-sizing: border-box;
}

html,
body {
  width: 100%;
  min-height: 100vh;
  overflow-x: hidden;
}

body {
  font-family: Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif;
}

.header {
  min-height: 100vh;
  width: 550px;
  position: relative;
  text-align: center;
}

.header > img {
  height: 200px;
  width: 200px;
}

.header > img.left {
  float: left;
}

.header > img.right {
  position: absolute;
  bottom: 0;
  right: 0;
}

header > text > p {
  background-color: lemonchiffon;
}

header > text > p:nth-child(odd) {
  background-color: lightcyan;
}
```

```html
<div class="header">

  <h1>header header header</h1>

  <img src="data:image/jpeg;base64,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" class="left">
   
  <h2>First draft header....</h2>
  <div class="text">
    <p>draft draft draft draft draft draft draft draft draft draft draft draft draft draft</p>
    <p>draft draft draft draft draft draft draft draft draft draft draft draft draft draft</p>
    <p>draft draft draft draft draft draft draft draft draft draft draft draft draft draft</p>
    <p>draft draft draft draft draft draft draft draft draft draft draft draft draft draft</p>
    <p>draft draft draft draft draft draft draft draft draft draft draft draft draft draft</p>
    <p>draft draft draft draft draft draft draft draft draft draft draft draft draft draft</p>
    <p>draft draft draft draft draft draft draft draft draft draft draft draft draft draft</p>
    <p>draft draft draft draft draft draft draft draft draft draft draft draft draft draft</p>
    <p>draft draft draft draft draft draft draft draft draft draft draft draft draft draft</p>
    <p>draft draft draft draft draft draft draft draft draft draft draft draft draft draft</p>
    <p>draft draft draft draft draft draft draft draft draft draft draft draft draft draft</p>
    <p>draft draft draft draft draft draft draft draft draft draft draft draft draft draft</p>
    <p>draft draft draft draft draft draft draft draft draft draft draft draft draft draft</p>
    <p>draft draft draft draft draft draft draft draft draft draft draft draft draft draft</p>

   <img src="data:image/jpeg;base64,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" class="right">


  </div>
</div>
```

Is it ok?

Comment: unfortunately no, i am trying to get it without change any html.